# How to calculate the capacitance when there are more than one dielectric materials inside it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, capacitance

[image]

What will be the capacitance in this case?

$A=0.5m^2$, $d=0.1m$

$\kappa_1=2$, $\kappa_2=3$, $\kappa_3=4$, $\kappa_4=5$

**My first attempt:**

$$C_1=C_2=C_3=C_4=\frac{\epsilon_0\frac{A}{2}}{\frac{d}{2}}$$

$$=\frac{\epsilon_0A}{d}$$

$$=4.427\times10^{-11}F$$

Now,

$C_1'=\kappa_1\cdot C_1$

$C_2'=\kappa_2\cdot C_2$

$C_3'=\kappa_3\cdot C_3$

$C_4'=\kappa_4\cdot C_4$

Now, I have to find the equivalent capacitance of $C_1'$ and $C_3'$ (they are parallel) = ${C_p}_1$ (suppose). Then, I have to find the equivalent capacitance of $C_2'$ and $C_4'$ (they are parallel) = ${C_p}_2$ (suppose). Then I have to find the equivalent capacitance of ${C_p}_1$ and ${C_p}_2$ (they are in series) = $C_s$, which is the desired capacitance.

**Cause for dispute:**

My friends are saying something different. They are saying that we have to first find the equivalent capacitance of $C_1'$ and $C_2'$ (in series), and $C_3'$ and $C_4'$ (in series). Then we have to find the equivalent capacitance of the resultant to capacitances in parallel.

Who is correct, me or them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friends are correct. In general $C_1'$ and $C_3'$ are not in parallel, nor are $C_2'$ and $C_4'$. In order for them to be in parallel, the potential between $C_1'$ and $C_2'$ must be the same as that between $C_3'$ and $C_4'$, but this is not the case in general.

We can show this explicitly. Let $E_i$ denote the E-field in capacitor $C_i'$, pointing to the right. Let $V$ be the battery voltage. We have
$$\frac{d}{2}(E_1 + E_2) = V$$
$$\kappa_1 E_1=\kappa_2 E_2.$$
Solving for $E_2$ gives
$$E_2 = \frac{2V}{d}\frac{\kappa_1}{\kappa_1 + \kappa_2}.$$
The potential between $C_1'$ and $C_2'$ is then

$$V_{1-2}=\frac{d}{2}E_2=\frac{\kappa_1}{\kappa_1+\kappa_2}V.$$
Doing this for the bottom half of the capacitor will yield
$$V_{3-4}=\frac{\kappa_3}{\kappa_3+\kappa_4}V.$$
As you can see, $V_{1-2}$ and $V_{3-4}$ are not equal in general. If they are (i.e. $\kappa_1/\kappa_2 = \kappa_3/\kappa_4$), you can calculate the equivalent capacitance with either approach and you will get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

May be the task is underspecified. It all depends on the following:

- are there currents between k1 and k3, k2 and k4?
- If, by chance, they meet in the middle do they balance charges there as if there was a metal plate in the middle?

However, neglecting edges, there‘s a uniform electric field between the two plates. So it all boils down to two parallel series-caps.

Results in a little bit of a monster for the final equation, or in an ugly reciprocal form. Make your choice.